# DAX Concatenate not working on text fields

Tags: concatenation, dax

my .pbix is an import and I'm trying to take to simple text fields and create a DAX measure that concatenates 2 fields.

My DAX functions work on numbers and values, but when I try DAX functions on text fields like concatenate or concatenateX or combinevalues, none of these work

When I start building the simple formula, my power BI doesn't recognize the fields , despite the data imported into my PBIX.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so how did you resolve it? I've tried creating the fields in power Query with no issues, but my plan was to make conditional measures with my DAX concatenate measures.

I was able to create a really nice dashboard, but being able create additional functions, would be to take my report/dashboard to the next level. and I've been able to create plenty of DAKS measures using number values , but for some reason I can't seem to make measures out of text.

Help(!) Is appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the code you wrote? DAX text functions work as expected

Comment: Are MEASURES used for concatenating strings? Shouldn't that be a regular COLUMN?